# How can I add a legend to this plot (with ggplot())?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a problem adding a legend to the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
df = cbind(1980:2019,runif(40,0,1))
df=as.data.frame(df)
ggplot() + 
geom_rect(aes(xmin=1990, xmax=2001,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf), fill='red', alpha= 0.3)+
geom_line(data=df,aes(x=V1,y = V2), color = "darkred")+
theme_classic()
```

The legend should be for the red area . For example to show that red area was a recession.

Can anyone help? thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: put the fill and color inside the aes to get a legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
df = cbind(1980:2019,runif(40,0,1))
df=as.data.frame(df)
ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=1990, xmax=2001,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf, fill='legend_2'), alpha= 0.3)+
  geom_line(data=df,aes(x=V1,y = V2,color = "legend_1"))+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "some name", values = "red")+
  scale_color_manual(name = "some other name", values = "darkred")+
  theme_classic()
```